# Django: combining method and class inside views to share same url

Tags: django

I'm working on Django project where I have an app which has a page with a drop down and a chart that is generated from data (which is queried from the database and passed into an API url). I'm using class based views and APIView and have a get method which is creating a response to pass some Json data into a url. I have the following class in my views.py set up and working.

views.py

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
    #generated through code
       data = {
        "labels": all_times,
        "default": all_data,
       }  

        return Response(data)
```

In order have access to this data, I have my url set as:

```
url(r'^display/api/chart/data/$', views.ChartData.as_view()),
```

This data from the API is used to generate a ChartJS graph in my template html of this app. The chart is set up so that it seeks the Json data from the url display/api/chart/data/ and uses Ajax to populate itself. Here is how the chart is generated:

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = 'display/api/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var defaultLabels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        defaultLabels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        console.log(data)
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: defaultLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Measurable',
                    data: defaultData,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }


         }]
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
{% endblock %}
</script>
```

I also have another method in the same views file as follows:

views.py

```
def DropdownDisplay(request):
    items= #query from database
    if (request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax()):

        print(request.POST)

    return render(request, 'DisplayData/Display.html',{'dropdown':items})
```

This method is used to generate a dropdown in the page. The url for this is set up in the same urls.py file as follows:

```
url(r'^graph/', views.DropdownDisplay, name='Display-Dropdown')
```

Note: they are in the same views.py and urls.py file, I just separated them in this post for formatting purposes.

Now, I'm running into an issue. When I go to /display, the graph works, but the drop down does not. When I go to /display/graph, the drop down works but the graph does not. I can tell it is because in my urls.py, I have separate urls for each class and method, so they only work under their respective url.

However, I would like to combine them so that both the generation of the graph, and the population of the dropdown, work under one url, which will be /display.

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be a part of the same page, both the functionalities should be inside a form under one view. If not, there should not be one single url for two separate functionalities. Your question is a bit ambiguous. If you can clearly state the functionality, would be helpful.

Comment: Basically, I need to generate the REST API through ChartData class, but I also need to call DropdownDisplay method in order to populate a drop down. I'm asking how I can combine them so I can do both in the same page.